# java string.format function Format flag exception

Tags: java, string

I am getting following error while running the jar file. 
It was working in JDK 1.6 but throws error in JRE 1.8. 
The jar file is working fine in eclipse, but when i export it the following error comes.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = s, Flags = #
at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
at GenerateTTUMFile.padRight(GenerateTTUMFile.java:145)
at GenerateTTUMFile.generate_TTUMFile(GenerateTTUMFile.java:119)
at GenerateFilesOutwardCredit.main(GenerateFilesOutwardCredit.java:43)
```

I am using the below mentioned function.

```
public static String padRight(String s, int n) { 
    return String.format("%1$#" + n + "s", new Object[] { s });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The # flag can be applied to the %o, %x, %e, and %f format specifiers, but will throw Exception for **%s**

> If the `#` flag is given and the argument is not a `Formattable` ,
>   then a `FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException` will be thrown.

From the docs of [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

```
The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax:

%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

So `%1$#(n)s` means that for the flag value you have `#` and a conversion of `s` (string).

Since `java.lang.String` does not implement the Formattable interface, the Exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%-" + n + 's', s);
}

public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%" + n + 's', s);
}
```

---

**Demo**

```
System.out.println("0123456789|");
System.out.print(padRight("abc", 10));
System.out.println('|');
System.out.print(padLeft("abc", 10));
System.out.println('|');
```

**Output**

```
0123456789|
abc       |
       abc|
```

See details in [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)